# Screen blanking password correspondence issue?

Tags: touch-screen

On an Android or other mobile device, why should the idle time that needs to pass before the screen goes blank have to correspond with the time a password is required to unlock the screen?

For instance, on my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo, with password protected lock screen unlocking, (by default), as soon as I stop interacting with the screen:

1. after about 28 seconds the screen goes dim, alerting the user that the screen is about to go blank and lock
2. after about 7 seconds the screen goes blank and locks

But wouldn't it be more useful any productive if you could set

1. the time the screen would take to go blank and save power and prevent unwanted input
2. and the time that would need to go by before a password would be required to lock the screen (instead of a simple swipe)

Separately (e.g. 35 secs to lock, but 5 minutes until a password (or pin) would be required instead of a simple swipe to unlock the blanked screen?

And, if you really need to password protect the screen immediately as often happens (e.g. You need to put the phone down on the table), just press the power button once to lock the screen immediately and make the screen go blank at the same time.

---

Surely, this would make it possible to usethe phone w/o having to enter a password so frequently and still have the same level of protection via the power button.

So why hasn't anyone (e.g. Samsung) implemented this yet?

---

Anyways , I've now noticed the feature was already there. Here are the screenshots illustrarting this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designers have to deal both with the end user and the business and sometimes little annoyances like this make their way in to the market because, "shipping is a feature"

There are many smartphone manufacturers and I assure you some of them do exactly what you describe and then some.

For example, [Android Lollipop has a baked in feature](http://www.androidauthority.com/on-body-detection-lollipop-smart-unlock-595999/) where your phone can tell when you're holding it and doesn't lock (require a password) until you set it down on a still flat surface somewhere.